# Orientação a objeto em python

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, tkinter

Eu sou iniciante em Python, fiz alguns cursos e estou tentando aprender tkinter, achei uma playlist no youtube com um cara que fez um app de BTC trading com tkinter e ele criou uma classe para poder abrir mais de uma janela, tipo, quando eu selecionar uma janela esta poder abrir outra e assim em diante, tem MUITA coisa que não entendi, procurei alguns tutoriais sobre classes na internet mas não entrou muito bem na minha cabeça ainda.

```
class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand= True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        frame = StartPage(container, self)

        self.frames[StartPage] = frame

        frame.grid(row=0, column = 0, sitcky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
```

Minhas duvidas estão a respeito das linhas

```
container = tk.Frame(self)
frame = StartPage(container, self)
```

Eu não entendi como fica a questão do self nessas linhas, esses parametros serão passadas quando a classe for chamada? Eu tenho grandes duvidas a respeito de classes, se alguém tiver uma fonte pode ser em portugues ou ingles eu agradeceria bastante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso tem muito pouco a ver com orientação a objetos, e muito mais a ver com tkinter.

Eu mesmo acho muito ruim o design de herdade as classes da aplicação de classes do tkinter. Desde o começo da década de 90, em programação em C++ para Windows, e, infelizmente, toda a documentação do tkinter faz como nesse seu exemplo: herda a parte principal do aplicativo do componente de janela do framework (no caso, a classe SeaofBTCapp herdando de tkinter.Tk).

Não se ganha quase nada com isso, a não ser que alguém deve ter achado bonitinho lá atrás, na programação de Windows. Mas o seu programa não tem muito a ver com uma janela para SER uma janela, o que essa herança implica. É muito mais simples se ele *tiver* uma janela. Daí ele faz as contas e transações de rede e arquivo que tem que fazer, e quando for interagir com o usuário, aí sim, usa os métodos da janela.

No "mundo real" alguém acordou para isso faz uns 10 anos, e escreveram alguns bons artigos - um debate de "composição vs herança". Isso é: seu programa pode ser uma classe que tem vários atributos, entre eles uma janela (composição) ou ser uma janela (herança). Infelizmente, embora seja quase consensual que composição é melhor em termos de manutenção do programa, esse esclarecimento não se deu nas documentações e exemplos existentes.

Entrando especificamente na sua dúvida: no tkinter, o primeiro parâmetro de cada componente sempre é o seu "pai" - no caso de uma única janela, em geral essa janela. Agora, por conta da escolha de design, a janela principal do programa **é o próprio programa**. Ou seja, o "self". 
Então a classe que poderia apenas se preocupar com a lógica de entradas e saídas e transações de troca de moeda, o que já é complicado o suficiente, tem que se preocupar também em acomodar todos os métodos e atributos para gerenciar uma aplicação tkinter - que são da ordem de 250 items.

Você pode ter um programa funcionando exatamente do mesmo jeito se não herdade de nada sua classe, e criar um atributo `self.window = tkinter.Tk()` - pronto, os 262 atributos necessários para gerenciar a aplicação em janela ficam isolados em self.window  - e você fica livre para ter atributos tais como self.wallet_number, self.balance, self.last_quotation  para a lógica da sua aplicação.

Orientação a objetos é muito legal, mas quando é entendida organicamente. O uso errado desse estilo de aplicações por herança de janelas, apenas força um uso não natural que complica e mistura conceitos, dái a coisa estar tão confusa para você.

OOP até permtie que você crie uma classe que não se preocupe *nada* com a interface - só com a lógica da aplicação mesmo - e aí uma subclasse que herde tudo o que essa faz, e *crie* atributos adicionais para serem a janela, as entradas de texto, e os botões do seu programa.

Vamos pensar numa aplicação duas ordens de grandeza mais simples - em vez de querer partir de uma carteira de bitcoin, sem entender direito de como funciona uma carteira, sem entender direito como funciona o tkinter, e sem entender direito como funciona orientação a objetos (é - parece que você estava num mato sem cachorro) - uma agenda simples, que só tenha telefone, e-mail e nome de pessoas.

Em Python, podemos usar uma classe Pessoa para ter os dados de nome, endereco e telefone. Daí cada pessoa que estiver na memoria do programa vai ser uma "instancia" da classe, ou um "objeto":

```
class Pessoa:
   def __init__(self, nome="", email="", telefone=""):
        self.nome = nome
        self.email = email
        self.telefone = telefone
```

Pronto. Em Python, temos as listas. Nossa aplicação simples pode manter os dados de várias pessoas numa lista. E ter uma classe para a aplicação em tkinter. A aplicação pode ter: um espaço para  o nome, um para o e-mail, um para o telefone, um botão para "próximo" um botão para "anterior" e um botoão para "novo". Não vamos ter várias instâncias da aplição, mesmo criando uma classe pra ela - a vantagem aí é que vários métodos ligados a classe podem compartilhar dados: por exemplo, todos podem ter acesso a lista de nomes.

import tkinter

class Person:
    def **init**(self, name="", email="", phone=""):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.phone = phone

def create_entry(root, label):
    frame = tkinter.Frame(root)
    label = tkinter.Label(frame, text=label + ":")
    variable = tkinter.Variable()
    entry = tkinter.Entry(frame, textvariable=variable)
    label.pack()
    entry.pack()
    frame.pack()
    return variable

```
class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tkinter.Tk()
        self.name_var = create_entry(self.window, "Nome")
        self.email_var = create_entry(self.window, "Email")
        self.phone_var = create_entry(self.window, "Telefone")
        self.data = [Person()]

        button_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.window)
        button_frame.pack()
        button_prev = tkinter.Button(self.window, text="<", command=self.previous)
        button_new = tkinter.Button(self.window, text="+", command=self.new)
        button_next = tkinter.Button(self.window, text=">", command=self.next)

        button_prev.pack(side="left"); button_new.pack(side="left"); button_next.pack(side="left")
        self.index = 0

    def save_person_data(self):
        person = self.data[self.index]
        person.name = self.name_var.get()
        person.email = self.email_var.get()
        person.phone = self.phone_var.get()

    def display_person_data(self):
        person = self.data[self.index]
        self.name_var.set(person.name)
        self.email_var.set(person.email)
        self.phone_var.set(person.phone)

    def next(self):
        self.save_person_data()
        self.index += 1
        if self.index >= len(self.data):
            self.index = 0
        self.display_person_data()

    def previous(self):
        self.save_person_data()
        self.index -= 1
        if self.index < 0:
            self.index = len(self.data) - 1
        self.display_person_data()

    def new(self):
        self.save_person_data()
        self.data.append(Person())
        self.index = len(self.data) - 1
        self.display_person_data()


app = App()
tkinter.mainloop()
```

Pronto - essa é uma aplicação minima que deve ser mais compreensivel. A classe da aplicação *tem* uma janela, e tem as variáveis para setar e ler o conteúdo das entradas de texto.
Se colocassemos mais dois métodos e os botões respectivos - para salvar e carregar os dados do disco, já poderia funcionar como uma mini agenda.
E fica fácil ver que em todos os métodos de uma classe, o "self" sempre é o próprio objeto, e "self.algo" é o atributo correspondente - com a classe pequena temos controle sobre todos os métodos e atributos da mesma e isso fica mais perceptível.

Comment: Sua resposta foi fantástica mas ainda estou "penando" para entender isso tudo, me deparei com um código, 
class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master

Não entendi a ideia do Frame.__init__ nem um pouco

Comment: é claro que essaa resposta não é suficiente para "entender orientação a objeto" como um todo. Mas deveria ter ficado claro que qualquer código que tenha classes herdando do tkinter é um péssimo código - e pior ainda para tentar ser usado de exemplo.

Comment: entendi, é porque eu costumo entender a maioria das classes mas essas do tkinter eu bugo completamente, você acha mais vantagem aprender pyqt em vez de tkinter?

Comment: PyQt e mais sofisitcado, moderno e vai deixar você fazer mais coisas - mas não acho que a maioria dos exemplos vai estar livre do mesmo problema desses. Isso deveria estar bem claor na minha resposta: herdar das classes do toolkit é uma prática ruim. Péssima. mas todo mundo faz assim, por que todo mundo fazia assim desde 1991.
PyQt vai ser mais dificil de entender um pouco, por que a abstração por cima dos métodos de C++ em alguns pontos é muito fina, e fica complicado.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, essas linhas são chamadas quando a classe `SeaofBTCapp` é instanciada. `self` faz referência à instância. Como é tradicional em OOP, instâncias possuem valores diferentes para os mesmos atributos, então é necessário fazer referência à instância às vezes.

A fonte oficial para classes é https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: acho que essa resposta não esclarece muita coisa, não é mesmo? A minha pode estar exagerada, mas não sei se para alguém que está com o grau de confusão que o OP está por pegar uma aplicação muito grande, isso vai esclarecer algo.